# itemize within tables is no longer working

Tags: tables, lists, itemize, tabulary

I'm new to this forum (and relative new to LaTeX).

After upgrading MiKTeX to the latest version yesterday evening I'm
unable to compile a document containing an `\begin{itemize} ... \end{itemize}` construction within an `tabulary` or `tabularx` environment.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt, paper=a4, twoside, headinclude, footinclude, headsepline, footsepline, BCOR=5mm]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\setlength{\tymin}{50pt}
\setlength{\tymax}{\linewidth}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[hbt!]
\captionabove{Test Table}
\label{tab:Test Table}
\centering
    \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{LL}
%    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}
    \rowcolor{black!90}
    \toprule
    \color{white}\textbf{Column 1} & \color{white}\textbf{Column 2}\\
    \midrule
    Col 1 / Row 1 & Col 2 / Row 1:
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Item 1 with a long text which must be wrapped into the next line
                \item Item 2 with a long text which must be wrapped into the next line
            \end{itemize}\\
    \hline
    Col 1 / Row 2 & Col 2 / Row 2\\
    \hline
    Col 1 / Row 3 & Col 2 / Row 3 and again, a column with a long text which must be wrapped into the next line\\
    \hline
    Col 1 / Row 4 & Col 2 / Row 4\\
    \bottomrule
%    \end{tabularx}
    \end{tabulary}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The errormessages for `tabulary` are:

```
Zeile 35: Undefined control sequence \end{tabulary}
...
Zeile 35: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{tabulary}
...
Zeile 35: Undefined control sequence \end{tabulary}
```

and for `tabularx` they are:

```
Zeile 34: Undefined control sequence \end{tabularx}
....
Zeile 34: Undefined control sequence \end{tabularx}
```

Before upgrading to the latest version everything was ok (tested with `tabularx`).
Does anybody has a hint for me why it's no longer working or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2):

Well for me your example already chokes (unsurprisingly) on the undefined `\rowcolor`, `\color`, `\toprule`. Are you sure you tested really exactly this code?

Anyway: Looking at the code of `tabulary` I would say that lists can't work in the LCRJ column of `tabulary`. The content of such cells are processed first in columns of type l and there lists are not allowed. This is not new: `tabulary` has not been changed recently.

`tabularx` should work fine (and works fine for me in an up-to-date miktex if I add all the missing packages in your example).

Comment: Hi Ulrike, you were right. I missed the packages in my democode. Sorry. It's working fine with tabularx for me and not with tabulary as you described.